# How to specify path location of files inside SpringBoot property file

Tags: spring, spring-boot, properties, configuration-files

Here are 2 values defined in my spring boot application which resides in resources/config/application-dev.properties.

```
TLS.store.location=/app/eas/certs/cics.jks
logging.file=/app/eas/logs/easApp.log
```

And the jks key store location is accessed in spring-context xml as below :

```
<sec:keyStore type="${TLS.store.type}" password="${TLS.store.pass}"
                          file="${TLS.store.location}" />
```

Though log files are generated very well, the TLS.store.location value is not detected as expectedly. The cics jks files are available in root folder (for now it is windows - c:\app\eas\certs\cics.jks)

I ran my app as follows :`java -jar -Dspring.profiles.active=dev target/test.jar`

Error in log file is as follows :

```
`Could not resolve placeholder 'TLS.store.location' in value "<sec:trustManager``
```

Since the error is thrown only for TLS.location.store - I guess it could not access the file location as expected ?

How to resolve this ?

Comment: try `file:app/eas/certs/cics.jks`

Comment: classpath:${TLS.store.location}

Comment: Sorry -both options didn't work out as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Resolved. Primarily it has got to do with jar clash!!

The dependent module had a separate springwebmvc dependency while the parent springboot app had another version.

Once I made all dependencies in a uniform manner it started working as expected.